# Rewrite the URL from Database

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need some help.
What I found here is this:

[URL Rewrite query database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972608/url-rewrite-query-database)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But I cant change it to what I need :-(

Here is what I need.

www.mySite.de/person.php?p=122

www.mySite.de/alias-of-person-from-database

Where is the name of the variable I need to have to get the recordset from my database?

It must be some $_GET, or?

Anyone can help me?
Cheers,
Denis

Comment: It's not clear. Please explain with examples, specially the part of the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Dynamically Rewrite a URL like Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907730/how-to-dynamically-rewrite-a-url-like-facebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my answer here.

[How to Dynamically Rewrite a URL like Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907730/how-to-dynamically-rewrite-a-url-like-facebook)

Thanks Gumbo!

Cheers,
Denis