# how to do url routing in php

Tags: php, hyperlink

Sorry, I don't know what should be exact technical term for my problem statement so the title of my thread might be misleading/confusing. Also that's the reason why i am not able to search my problem solution on google.

Okay, so I'm developing a simple social network for my users. I want each user to have their own profile link.

for example, if the username of user is 'xyz' then his profile link should be 'http://example.com/user/xyz

now how do i create this "virtual" link?

Edit: Okay, I learned that it's about mod_rewrite and I also got a similar question [How to Dynamically Rewrite a URL like Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907730/how-to-dynamically-rewrite-a-url-like-facebook)

Comment: read about `mod_rewrite` if your web server is apache. Or generally read about URL rewriting on google.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907730/how-to-dynamically-rewrite-a-url-like-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes with PHP is a very delicate matter. mod_rewrite can help you in the beginning, but after becoming a mess and will f*** you rather than help, especially when it is a "big" software which needs to be scalable.

Remembering that "routes" are not part of a specific application, it is just a nomenclature for a "server" that interprets a request for a "client" and thus returns a specific value for the "client" for the configuration of that request. Ie, the "router" is basically a server.

What I recommend for you to look is to study the HTTP protocol, REST and so on.

This surely will help you in many things, so knowing how the HTTP protocol works, how to handle it with PHP. Besides you stay fit to designing a skill webservice to your social network, and make routes easily.

There are several libraries that work with routes in PHP, like: Slim Framework, Zaphpa, Respect/Rest, Toro, Aura Router and so on...

Hope this helps.